# How to set dynamic text to edit text from the custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I want to set dynamic text to my edit text from the custom keyboard.

For example if I press "a" from the my keyboard then I want to set clipboard data to my edit text.

I use following demo for custom keyboard,

```
    https://github.com/blackcj/AndroidCustomKeyboard
```

And it work perfect, but I want to just customize it, I want to override my functionality on it, if I am press any of alphabet then I want to perform my action on application edit text.

Please suggest how to do this , and this is possible to paste my clip board data to edittext from the my custom keyboard any key event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have call back method for each key pressed by user, so you can set your custom test to edit text.
You must have class that extends **InputMethodService** which overrides **onKeyDown** method where you can write code to set custom text to edit text based on key pressed by user.

Comment: i find that file, but how to find edit text of any application so i paste data to that edit text means how to setText work in my case ?

Comment: getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText("your text", 1);

Comment: thanks @android_team you save my lots of time, due to my low stackover flow point i am not able to accept answer, but this is accepted ans from my side , thanks